# Eclipse RCP: How can i make my code more enhanced?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, optimization, rcp

I have been told to design a Tree , clicking on Node should give detail about a person and should display an Image. I used If-Else statement to do this and was told that it is not a standard of coding, how can i make it really efficient so that it follows coding standards.

This is my code for a Eclipse RCP View.. It would display the content in table and image of the person when a node with a person is selected.
[RCP Application Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AduPV.png)

```
package com.cerner.imagetagger.view;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class JViewer extends ViewPart{
    public JViewer() {}
    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        parent.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
        final Tree tree = new Tree(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        Label labelImg = new Label(parent,SWT.NONE);
        Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        final ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
        loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/default.png"));
        final Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), loader.data[0]);
        labelImg.setImage(image);

        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);

        TreeItem item0 = new TreeItem(tree, 0);
        item0.setText("Designation");

        TreeItem item1 = new TreeItem(item0, 0);
        item1.setText("Software Engineer");

        TreeItem item2 = new TreeItem(item1, 0);
        item2.setText("Tansheet Izhad");

        TreeItem item21 = new TreeItem(item1, 0);
        item21.setText("Nikhil Gautam");

        String[] titles = {"Name", "Age"};

        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
            column.setText(titles[i]);
        }


        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText(0, "");
        item.setText(1, "");

        for (int i=0; i<titles.length; i++) {
            table.getColumn (i).pack ();
        }     

        tree.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                String treeNode = "";
                String resultwb= "";
                String result="";
                TreeItem[] selection = tree.getSelection();

                for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++)

                    treeNode += selection[i] + " ";

                resultwb = treeNode.replaceAll("[{}]", "");
                result=resultwb.replace("TreeItem ","");      


                if(result.matches("(.*)Tansheet Izhad(.*)"))
                {
                    item.setText(0, "TI");
                    item.setText(1, "23");   
                    loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/tansheet.png"));
                    final Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), loader.data[0]);
                    labelImg.setImage(image);

                }

                else    
                {
                    item.setText(0, "NULL");
                    item.setText(1, "NULL");
                    loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/default.png"));
                    final Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), loader.data[0]);
                    labelImg.setImage(image);
                }           
            }
        });    

        tree.getItems()[0].setExpanded(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {}

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to go back and ask whoever told you this what they mean. It is not clear what you are asking and since we don't know anything about your application is hard to make any comments.

Comment: I have been given to make an application which is quite simple and basic in functionality. It would display the Information about the person in Table and Image of the selected selected person in Tree Node.
e.g If i select a person in Tree, it would Display his Name and Age in a Table and his image in a View.